# custom options validation

Tags: validation

[image]

generated output custom option magento admin without any programming, but what I'm looking if default quantity set 0, product does not add in basket until any 1 field (greater then 0).

Comment: Try required field No in backend that particular product

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you illustrate it with examples? What validation result do you expect from which input?

Comment: I would like to keep qty 0 in all field default, atleast 1 field < 0, so cutomer able to add product in basket

Answer (score 0):

The Product does not add in basket because that option fiels is required. thats why that is not added.once go to

```
admin panel-->catalog-->manage products-->select product-->custom options-->fields required set to "No"
```